# Using Esri Map Server in JOSM?

Tags: arcgis-online, map-service, josm

How can I bring into JOSM a Esri Map Service?
For example:

```
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer
```

Googling around I found [How can I create an adapter between the ArcGIS REST interface and WMS or TMS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6276/how-can-i-create-an-adapter-between-the-arcgis-rest-interface-and-wms-or-tms) but what if the Esri map service does not have WMS or TMS enabled?

Comment: Based on [this answe][1]r you can only use wmts.     [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123037/locating-wms-on-esri-basemap

Comment: try to use SOAP URL :    http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer?wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMS and TMS was not enabled, but WMTS was (thank you @wetland), so I used that instead. What worked for me was:

```
http://myurl.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/foldername/servicename/MapServer/WMTS?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=getcapabilities&f=json
```

I tacked on the `&f=json` because service directory browsing was disabled and I think that was throwing off josm too.